# How might I display a field twice in a node using different field formatters?

Tags: theming, media

**Question:**

How can I show the `field_showcase_headshot` field both as a picture on screen and as a download link?

**Set up**:

From the load tab of Devel, I have a few fields on this node.

[image]

The field here is Showcase Headshot. It is currently set to display on the screen as follows

[image]

But we'd like to include a download link to the original image in the fashion shown here.

[image]

That is, we'd like to append something like the following to the text on the page.

Showcase Download:
headshot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [Display Suite](https://www.drupal.org/project/ds) module to create a new dynamic field. On the manage display page select the field from the Node section.

https://www.video2brain.com/en/lessons/using-display-suite-dynamic-fields

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 options available for this to do.

1. By linking the image to its image path from the site. This can be achieve using a module https://www.drupal.org/project/image_link_formatter.
2. By using download module and custom field theme formatter.
   In this you need to enable the download file module https://www.drupal.org/project/download_file.
   And than create customize the field view using the field template.